# How to print a list with a delay between each item in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, list, for-loop, delay

```
<html>
    <body>
        //Id for each item
        <p id=1></p>
        <p id=2></p>
        <p id=3></p>
        <script>
            for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                window.setTimeout(press, 1000);
                //Should use For loop variable to fetch and print specific element's Id
                function press() {
                    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = i;   
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm a bit of a noob to all of this. Most of these commands I got from w3schools and I'm just trying to piece everything together bit by bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an argument through to the timeout function, so we can use that to display the first value, then increment it and start the timeout again if the value is `<= 3`:

```js
window.setTimeout(press, 1000, 1);
//Should use For loop variable to fetch and print specific element's Id
function press(j) {
  document.getElementById(j).innerHTML = j;
  if (++j <= 3) window.setTimeout(press, 1000, j);
}
```

```html
//Id for each item
<p id=1></p>
<p id=2></p>
<p id=3></p>
```

Comment: I know this not the place to write comments like this, but I learnt something today, thanks Nick.

Comment: @Spangle personally that's a policy I disagree with... but no doubt someone will come along later and delete it (or you can, now I've seen it)

Comment: I will just leave it and let someone come along haha

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem perfectly. Now I just have understand it and figure out how to recreate it by myself (Would my comment be deleted by someone else too? Since Thank You's aren't allowed).

Also, what does the parameter do in the setTimeout command?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to JavaScript would be to use CSS for this.  As a bonus, your page will still work even if JavaScript is disabled.

First, let's start with some clean, valid markup:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="popIn">
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      <p>Paragraph 2</p>
      <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, your CSS (such as in a `<style>` tag in `<head>`), add a keyframe animation that sets the visibility to `visible` right at the last second:

```
@keyframes popIn {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Now, add a rule to select all direct descendants of `.popIn`.  In this selector, `>` means direct decendant of, and `*` means anything.  The rule will set up our animation.

```
.popIn > * {
  animation: 1s popIn;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you run this code now, you'll see that after 1 second, everything appears all at once.  All we have to do is select the individual paragraphs in-order and change the animation duration.

```
.popIn *:nth-child(2) {
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.popIn *:nth-child(3) {
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

Now, the paragraphs will display one after the other, and no scripting was necessary!

Comment: I've never worked with CSS before (Still a noobie to html and coding in general), but it looks like it could be way more useful than Javascript. I'll probably start learning CSS as soon as I feel comfortably with Javascript

Answer (score 2):

In your case the `setTimeout` fires only once as it isn't waiting with the loop and `i` being declared in the scope, hence after the loop it is equal to `3`.

You could use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Example_1_Basic_syntax) as follows to pass the argument and do a [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) when `i` exceeds number paras:

```js
let i = 1;

const a = window.setInterval(press, 1000, i);

//Should use For loop variable to fetch and print specific element's Id
function press() {
  document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = i++;
  if (i > 3)
    window.clearInterval(a);
}
```

```html
//Id for each item
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
<p id="3"></p>
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the loop was only running once because of the scope, I just couldn't figure out how to keep it in scope. Thanks for the clarification, yours is by far the simplest and easiest to understand!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively you could make the loops like this :

```html
<html>
<body>
    //Id for each item
    <p id=1></p>
    <p id=2></p>
    <p id=3></p>
    <script>
        function press(i) {
            if (i < 3) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    i++;
                    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = i;
                    press(i);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        press(0);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, I just couldn't figure out where to place the variables to keep them in scope and let the loop finish.
I also didn't know I could expand the setTimeout command like that, I assumed it wouldn't read the getElementById if I put it inside of the command.